# Apache: simultaneous connections to single script

Tags: apache, cgi, connection, simultaneous

How does Apache (most popular version nowadays, i guess) handle a connection to a script when this script is already being executed for another connection?

My guess has always been - upon receipt of a request to a script, script's contents are copied-to-memory/compiled/executed, and IF during this process there's another request to this script - same things happen (assuming Apache does not lock the script file, and simply gives another share of memory/cpu for another compilation/memory-storage/execution)

Or is there a queuing/waiting mechanism involved?

Assuming this additional connection is afforded enough memory, cpu, and does not pass maximum connections setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickly (and easy) answer is every request is processes by a new process.
Apache listens in some port and for each request create a new process that handles that request. That means no shared memory.

Also take a look to processes with "ps" command, you will see one "http" process for each request.

Take a look here for more complex working: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/worker.html
and look at google too :) http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/apache/ch01_02.htm

Comment: the worker core module's intestines is what i was looking for, thanks! (don't appreciate you trying to googleit'ing me though *mad face here* :D)

Comment: Take the case of PHP, the child processes either invoke a SO version of the PHP complier/RTS if mod_php5 is enabled or a child php-cgi if,say, mod_suphp is enabled.  In the first case you might also have a PHP opcode cache such as APC which cached compiled copies of PHP modules.   As Neil says, they wll all run as parallel processes.  If your script accesses shared resources (such as writing to an application data file), then you need to handle that possibility in your script, but there are standard patterns for this.